# How to add a conditional breakpoint in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I am basically a .net developer so didn't know much about vb6. I was able to add breakpoints but didn't know how to add condition in it by right clicking on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Debug Menu -> Add Watch -> Type the expression in the expression textbox (e.g. variablename > 100) and select the checkbox "Break When Value Is True". It worked for me so thought of sharing with others who may need it.